# very old battery but healthy - replace?

Tags: battery, battery-testing

the battery in my vehicle was manufactured in the 41st week of 2017. I've never had any issues with it. In my online research, many sources say batteries last from 3-5 years, which would make my battery archaic. When I tested it with a multimeter, it read 12.4V with the engine off. I've never had any issues starting the car.

What explains how this battery is still alive despite it's age? Is the 3-5 year age expectancy accurate? Should I replace it? Given how old it is, I have it in my mind that the battery could die suddenly, any day now. What should I do to stay ahead of it's inevitable death?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the battery is fine, there's no point in replacing it.
3-5 years is a ballpark value; I've seen batteries last twice that without any problem as well.

Replace it when you get problems with it. If that's impractical, you can ask a workshop to do a load test of it, where they measure the voltage with a load attached. This can show how it deteriorates, so it can potentially be changed before you get problems - if you do the test regularly.